# 'return' not breaking out of Function when using '%' operator

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a function to churn through a bunch of strings, test them for some criteria, and if they pass add them to a return string. The return string is supposed to remain as < 400 chars. But when I run it, it seems that when it hits the return statement, it just jumps directly to the next object in the %{} instead of breaking out of the function and returning the string. Do I need to do this differently?

```
Function Get-AcceptableString()
{
    param(
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Key,
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Value,
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$json_path         
    )
    $formattedString = ""
    $json_file = Get-Content -raw -Path $json_path
    $json_object = ConvertFrom-Json $json_file 
    $charcount = 0
    $Value.Split(',').TrimStart(' ') | %{
        $format = $_
        if($charcount + $format.Length -gt 400){
            return $formattedString
        }
        $testResult = Test-Thing $_ $json_object $Key
        if($testResult){
            $formattedString += $format + ','
            $charcount += $format.length
        }
    }
    return $formattedString
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%{} does a foreach-object, which is its own function. So return was breaking out of that function, returning to the loop it was set in, which caused it to continue looping.

Needed to use a basic foreach instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).